# Can particle object instances act as obstacles in a fluid simulation?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to use a particle emitter in a fluid simulation, where the particles (based on an object instance I've linked the emitter to) cause splashes each time they hit the fluid they hit.
I've tried making both the particle emitter an obstacle in the fluid simulation and also the object instance the particles are based on (and that object is within the domain of the fluid simulation) but after I bake the fluid sim, I don't see the particles interacting with the fluid at all. Any ideas on how to make the particles cause splashes in the fluid? (BTW my original object that the particles are based on will interact as expected with the fluid if I deliberately crash it into the fluid). I imagine I'm doing something dumb, I just can't see what...
Any advice gratefully received!

Answer (score 2):

That will **not** work with the current release, since the (now old) fluid simulation in Blender is not designed to interact with non-fluid physics systems. I haven't checked, but maybe this will work with the new Mantaflow simulation that was added to the master branch recently. This will be in the next official Blender release.

Answer (score 0):

I also realized that you could just use the dynamic paint modifier to achieve a fake particle-fluid interaction. See: [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157815/fluid-sim-and-particles/163107#163107). It should look pretty realistic.