# Fluid Sim and Particles

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

So I have set up a particle emitter and a fluid sim, the emitter particles do not interact with the fluid even when I set the emitter as an obstacle, also tried setting the object as an obstacle but no luck. Can anyone help please, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to currently do this in Blender, as it takes a lot of RAM and computing time. In the future there may be support for this kind of thing in later versions of Blender. However, you can fake achieve a similar effect by subdividing the fluid a substantial amount, and using a dynamic paint modifier to produce waves on the surface. Add a dynamic canvas to the fluid (domain), and set the dynamic paint type to **waves**.[Faked particle interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boRSf.png)
[image]
Then set the particle emitter to have a dynamic ***brush***. Set the paint source to your particle system like in this picture:[image]Hope this helps!